# Combine 2 Functions to Write to an Attribute Array in jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, attributes

This is an extension of original question: [jQuery Extract Year from Date and Add Class to Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268592/jquery-extract-year-from-date-and-add-class-to-parent)

... but I need to extend it so that the 2 existing functions are combined and then extended to add an attribute in an array rather than a class.

**Original Snippets that added value as classes:-**

Gets date from div and add as class

```
jQuery(".publication-date").each(function(i) {
var yr = $(this).text().trim().split('/')[2];
jQuery(this).closest('.publication').addClass(yr);
});
```

Gets publication name from div and add as class

```
jQuery(".publication-name").each(function(i) {
var name = $(this).text().trim().replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-");
```

jQuery(this).closest('.publication').addClass(name); 
   });

**My Effort to combine and write into attribute of 'data-filter' where data-filter had any values separated with a comma ie. data-filter"2017, publicationname"**

```
$(".publication-date, .publication-name").each(function(i) {
var yr = $('.publication-date').text().trim().split('/')[2];
var name = $('.publication-name').text().trim().replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-");
value = yr + ',' + name;
$(this).closest('.publication').attr({
"data-filter": value
});
});
```

All input greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Glennyboy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that, in your HTML, each of your `.publication` `div` has one `.publicaton-date` `div` and one `publication-name` `div`, you can do something on the lines of:

```
$('.publication').each(function() {
    var yr = $(this).find('.publication-date').text().trim().split('/')[2];
    var name = $(this).find('.publication-name').text().trim().replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-");
    $(this).attr('data-filter', yr + ',' + name);
})
```

ie: Instead of looping through the `.publication-date` and `.publication-name` elements, loop through the `.publication` elements and find the date and year inside them.

Comment: Hi @miruda I'm looking to extend the above bit further by grouping the years (yr) automatically into a div with a class name of year + yr so for example a class of year2016 wrapped around every element that has a date of 2016. Then to show a div/span showing the actual year at the top of the grouped classes - so 2017, 2016 2015 etc. I'm guessing a combination of .wrapAll (for the classes) and .before / .prepend. (for the placeholder year value). Obviously only one set of year groups per year...

Comment: Its a little difficult for me to answer this without seeing some code. Can you show me what you are trying to achieve with the code you have tried for it?

Comment: Yes of course what I am trying to achive is to wrap a div around years and then also show what year it is. So right now I have:- `code` $(".grid").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
     
$('.2017').wrapAll( '<div class="year2017"></div>' );
$('.year2017').before('<div class="yeardiv"><h2>2017</h2></div>');

});
// bind event listener
$isotope.isotope( 'on', 'layoutComplete', onLayout );     `code`

Comment: I'm using jQuery Isotope and every time isotope runs I want to re-add and re-wrap Year Blocks with a year title. The full code is on the dev page here http://sanchez-stewart.webflow.io/publications (before </body> tag and you'll see that my rudimentary code does wrap, but it's not dynamic and keeps reproducing. Actually it's a linked issue to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685217/call-a-function-init-and-when-isotope-finishes-and-then-reset-on-next-run